# Raspberry Pi not booting up after reboot

Tags: networking

This morning I tried to connect my Raspberry Pi 4 via SSH (Windows 10 via a tool called OpenSSH). When I turned on my Pi, nothing happened. However, the Pi is on. When I pinged the hostname by typing in the "ping raspberrypi", the following error shows up:

Pinging raspberrypi[192.168.1.205] with 32 bits of data:

Reply from 192.168.1.249 destination host unreachable.

...

It worked yesterday. I'm not sure what the problem is. I did do some research regarding this problem, and the only thing that I found did not solve my problem.

Edit: There is no change in the light. It is just in a normal behavior. the Pi is connected via wireless.

Comment: the only thing you found? you mean things, plural, because "pi not booting" results in about a trillion results. Anyway. On the pi, what lights are on? Does any of them blink a particular pattern? Is 192.168.1.205 the correct IP for the Pi? How is the Pi connected to your network (wired/wireless)? What did you do before rebooting, i.e. any updates for example?